# Solving $\frac{2}{k}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$.

Tags: number-theory

for positive integer $x, y(x<y)$$, k(k>2)$, I want to solve this equation, minimizing the value $x+y$:
$$\frac{2}{k}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$
I think I solved it, but I can't think of any way to prove this, and I'm not even sure if I'm correct.

This is my answers:

let $k=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_t^{\alpha_t}$

if  $p_1=2$ and $\alpha_1=1$, $x=\frac{k(p_2+1)}{2p_2}, y=\frac{k(p_2+1)}{2}$

else, $x=\frac{k(p_1+1)}{2p_1}, y=\frac{k(p_1+1)}{2}$

Edit: I found out what was wrong from the comments, and this is the final answer.

````
import random

def gcd(a,b):
    if b > a:
        a, b = b, a
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
    
def is_prime(n, k=5):
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n <= 1 or n & 1 == 0:
        return False
    d = n - 1
    r = 0
    while d & 1 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        r += 1
    for _ in range(k):
        a = random.randint(2, n - 2)
        x = pow(a, d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
            continue
        for _ in range(r - 1):
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

def factorize(n):
    if n == 1:
        return []
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return [2, 2] + factorize(n // 4)
    if is_prime(n):
        return [n]
    while True:
        a = random.randint(1, n - 1)
        x = y = random.randint(1, n - 1)
        d = 1
        while d == 1:
            x = (pow(x, 2, n) + a) % n
            y = (pow(pow(y, 2, n) + a, 2, n) + a) % n
            d = gcd(abs(x - y), n)
        if d == n:
            continue
        return factorize(d) + factorize(n // d)

n = int(input())
factor = factorize(n)
factor.sort()

if factor[0] == 2:
    factor = factor[1:]

divisor = []
def dfs(arr, start, cnt, n, m, s=1):
    if cnt==m:
        divisor.append(s)
        return
    prev=0
    for i in range(start,n):
        if arr[i]!=prev:
            prev=arr[i]
            dfs(arr, i+1, cnt+1, n, m, s*arr[i])
for i in range(1, len(factor)+1):
    dfs(factor, 0, 0, len(factor), i)

divisor.sort()

p = [factor[0], 1]

for i in range(len(divisor)-1):
    if divisor[i+1]*p[1] < divisor[i]*p[0]:
        p = [divisor[i+1], divisor[i]] 

a, b = (n+n*p[1]//p[0])//2, (n+n*p[0]//p[1])//2
print(f'{a} {b}')
```
````

Comment: @achillehui They shouldn't have the same value. It's on the first line of the question.

Comment: for $k=12$ your formula gives $(9,18)$ but $(10,15)$ has a smaller sum, same for $k=21$ and $(14,42)$ versus $(15,35)$.

Comment: @zwim Do you have any ideas of finding them?

Comment: No, I just brute force tested some values. I have to think about the problem, your estimation doesn't seem to far off though, I mean it gives the best or second best on my few tries.

Comment: I think I get it. This is how I got my answers in the question:
$$(2x-k)(2y-k)=k^2$$
$$2x-k=\frac{k}{p}$$
$$2y-k=kp$$
But the $p$ part doesn't have to be an integer so I think I get it. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $(2x- k)(2y-k) = k^2$.  So the minimum occurs when you take the closest (but not equal) factors of $k^2$. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a simple expression similar to what you stated.  $\quad$ Agree with "p doesn't have to the an integer".

Comment: (As OP pointed out in deleted comment) We also need that the factors have the same parity as $k$ in order for $x, y$ to be integers.

Comment: Note: you can post [tio.run links](https://is.gd/CbZTgI).